How to use MathJax Offline In expo react native project
I have build a project using expo 52 with new architecture enabled.
I need to introduce MathJax to render formulas correctly in a Webview.
Currently Webview with remote cdn mathjax using below script works:
<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.7/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>

But users of my app should be able to use the app even offline so there will be no internet connection to the remote mathjax url.
How to make use of MathJax in expo projet offline ?
